# Google Healthcare NLP API Batch Processing

Tags: google-healthcare-api

I know we can process text using google healthcare API. There is a limit to this text. So I want to know if is there a way to process large-size clinical data(in GB or MB) using google healthcare NLP API. All the examples available are for single text argument.

To summarise, I would like to do a batch process large text file using google healthcare NLP API.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature that the API supports natively at this time, however the product team is aware that this is a feature request. You can submit your own feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/), or reach out to your sales/product contact if you have one.

To get this working today, I would recommend creating a batch pipeline, using something like Dataflow, to split the document into chunks of 10,000 characters or less (the current [limit](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/nlp#extracting_entities_relations_and_contextual_attributes)), and call the Healthcare API with each part individually.